# ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.(metamask)

Tags: solidity, truffle, metamask, react

i am working on truffle Pet-shop with react, i am using local blockchain ganache with metamask, The issue I'm encountering with my application is that when i am trying to call **deleteAdopter** function from UI, metamask opens and says

> ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.

but if i call **adopt** function it executes successfully on contract and my UI changes and pet mark as adopted.

here is the code
**Adoption.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Adoption {
    address[16] public adopters;

    // Adopting a pet
    function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);
        require(adopters[petId] == address(0), "already adopted pet");
        adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

        return petId;
    }

    // Retrieving the adopters
    function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
        return adopters;
    }
    
    //Releasing a pet 
    function deleteAdopter(uint petId) public returns(uint) {
        require(msg.sender == adopters[petId], "Only adopters can call this function");
        delete adopters[petId];
        return petId;
    }
}


// Releasing a pet
//  function release(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
//    require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

//    if (adopters[petId] == msg.sender) {
//      adopters[petId] = address(0);
//    }

//    return petId;
//  }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code first declares `adopters` as a fixed size array of 16 addresses, but then goes on and treats it as if it was a mapping of petId to address. To use it that way, declare it as follows:

```
mapping (uint => address) public adopters;
```

Comment: adopters is an array of 16 addresses, it means there are 16 pets, look at the adopt function require statement; so we should not mutate this, and this is working in remix where i can call deleteAdopters and then on calling getAdopters function it returns the updated array of addresses

Comment: Yes, instead of using an actual mapping, you are trying to map your pet IDs to the addresses by having the ID correspond to the index in the `adopters` array. If you really want to keep it that way, please show what is stored in `adopters` and the `petId` value, in order to find what's causing the error.

Comment: ok, in the ```adopters``` there are addresess of owners of pets, in the pet id the array index number is stored, so let say there are 16 pets (fixed), if someone wants to adopt a pet, the ```adopt``` function will store the address and petid will be store as the number of pet in that array, can i show you the ```adopterList```?

Comment: i have edited the question above, in the screenshot you can see the array of addresses

Comment: It's still not clear what you're passing into 'adopt()' as petId. Could you disclose that too?

Comment: i am getting pet list from a json file so  i map through all the pets so i am passing item.id as petid

Comment: Ok. So what's the actual value in the concrete case?

Comment: actual value? i think you mean what is the actual value of id? it is starting from 0 to 15 in json file, its property is 'id'

Comment: When you call adopt, how do you call it? Do you call `adopt(0)` or `adopt("0")`? It would really be helpful if you shared what actual transaction data was used, when the error occurred.

Comment: i call adopt(0), it is a number, this is the payload....payload:
adopterAddress: "0x67d30ef950015ab1a03e30ed5d5f2a26de196c4d"
petIndex: 12

Comment: What you posted resembles a JSON payload, but I mean the Ethereum transaction data. You could find it in MetaMask's DATA tab (see your screenshot, it has DETAILS selected instead of DATA).

Comment: ok, in the data:: 
FUNCTION TYPE:Contract Interaction

HEX DATA: 36 BYTES
0xcfc2034e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: this is hex data,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120740/discussion-between-pwagner-and-sultan).